# Trying to start CUPS service on a Chromebook running Ubuntu 14.04 via crouton

Tags: 14.04, printing, chromebook, chroot, crouton

Some background: I'm trying to set up CUPS on my Chromebook running Ubuntu 14.04 via crouton. I've downloaded and installed the necessary files and I am trying to get the CUPS service running. I have been referring to this guide https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Printing.

Whenever I try to manually start the service `sudo service cups start` I get thrown an "Unknown job" error. I've also tried to run CUPS via `sudo /usr/sbin/cupsd`. That command doesn't return any errors, but when I check to see if the service is running the same error as before appears. Does anyone have a solution to this?

I would also like to know how to properly add the `/usr/sbin/cupsd` command to `/etc/rc.local`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**WIP: (answered half of the question)**

1. > I would also like to know how to properly add the /usr/sbin/cupsd command to /etc/rc.local.

   a. Open gedit and paste the following (ignore "):

   > "#!/bin/sh -e
   >
   > sudo /usr/sbin/cupsd
   >
   > exit 0"

   b. Save the file as anyname.sh to /path/to/your/directory (its best to keep the path in your home directory:)

   c. Now, open terminal and type:

   `sudo gedit /etc/rc.local`

   d. Add the following line before exit 0.

   > sudo sh /path/to/your/directory/anyname.sh

Comment: I couldn't understand the other question that you asked, could you please elaborate or if your question 's been answered could you please accept it.

Comment: My main question was regarding how to deal with the "Unknown Job: cups" error I was getting. I can't really elaborate more than I have before regarding the error. My CUPS print service won't start on a fresh crouton install on my chromebook. That's pretty much it, sorry.

Comment: According to this post here you have to install `avahi-daemon` - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2174219&page=2

Comment: Or you can see here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/508612/which-init-daemon-starts-cups